# If statement hitting when it shouldn't

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, variable-assignment

I am running PHP 5.3 and am running running into a weird issue. Has anyone ever run into this problem before?

```
if(isset($_POST['favorites'])) { $fave = $_POST['favorites']; }
elseif(isset($_GET['favorites'])) { $fave = $_GET['favorites']; } else { $fave = 0; }

echo $fave; //echoes 0

if($fave=="addto"){ //This is called and looks like $fave is temporarily set to "addto"

echo $fave; //echoes 0

}
```

$fave is never set to "addto" but the if statement sees it as "addto" for some reason. Anyone ever encounter this before, or have any ideas of what to do to make it work the way it should?

Comment: datatype comparisons (loose typing) with == `If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically.` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see what values are printed out:

```
echo 'Post [Favorites]: ' . $_POST['favorites'] . '<br><br>';

if(isset($_POST['favorites'])) { 
    $fave = $_POST['favorites']; 
}elseif(isset($_GET['favorites'])) { 
    $fave = $_GET['favorites']; 
}else{ 
    $fave = 0; 
}

echo 'Value of \$fave: ' . $fave . '<br><br>';

if($fave=="addto"){ 
    //This is called and looks like $fave is temporarily set to "addto"
    echo 'Inside IF ADDTO. Value of \$fave: ' . $fave . '<br><br>';
}
```

Comment: Like Sable said above, you'll want to use `===` instead to make sure it's also the same datatype.

Comment: Post [Favorites]: <br><br>Value of \$fave: 0<br><br>Inside IF ADDTO. Value of \$fave: 0<br><br>

Answer (score 0):

Compare variable type using ===

```
if($fave==="addto")
```